# Jquery autocomplete select event fired but cannot replace different value at input

Tags: jquery

Here is my code :

```
select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item.value != "Match not found") {
                $(this).val(ui.item.value + "test");
            } else {
                $(this).val("");
            }
        }
```

I always received original `ui.item.value` after select an element from suggestion. I've never received `ui.item.value` + "test" value

Answer (score 0):

I think $(this) doesn't point to the correct object. Use the class name of the element instead of this.

Comment: I checked with debugger and (this) point to correct input element. I could do alert ($(this).val()) and showed me whatever my input is.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem. I forgot to prevent default behavior of showing selected element. Actually below is the solution. I don't need else statement because i use default behavior of choosing selected element.

```
select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item.value == "Match not found") {
                $(this).val("");
event.preventDefault();

            } 
        }
```